# react routing two cmponents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

very new to react router. i know this code isn't written the cleanest but how come when i click the button (Link to='/question') it renders
 and  BUT also renders the button still. i tried
setting it into a new route but unfortunately still doesn't work.
also is this how you would structure a basic router that needs to
render two separate components? i see i can do render={} or component={}
but not really sure how to render more than one component with one
router---- wit those two questions considered i basically just want
this button to render a new page ('/question') that has two components on it--- AFIB and QFIB and nothing else (right now its rendering the button and the two new components in addition... here is the code:

```
    <div class='qAndAContainer'>
      <Router>
      <Link to='/question'><button className="px-4 nextQuestion startButton py-2 bg-pink-600 text-white text-sm uppercase font-medium rounded hover:bg-pink-500 focus:outline-none" >Begin
      </button>
      </Link>
    <Route path='/question' component={(props) => (
       <QFIB {...props} />
     )} />
    <Route path='/question' component={(props) => (
       <AFIB {...props} />
     )} />
    </Router>

    </div>
  )
}

export default StartTest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Router's `Route` component is basically a glorified string-match for your browser's URL.

In this case, what you're presenting to React Router is three `Routes` with the same strings to match, so it shows them all!

This is actually useful, for example rendering the same navigation bar for `/dashboard` AND `/dashboard/messages`.

But in your case, you just want one route or the other. So for React Router to understand you just want one of many, you need to wrap your Routes with a `Switch` component. React Router will only render the first match it finds, from top to bottom. Try to order your Routes in a Switch from most specific (longest paths) to least to get the best results.

I don't really care for the `render` or `children` props of `Route` (although they have their purposes), I usually prefer composing just like normal components.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    // this will actually match /question123/asdf/kdkd?foo=bar as well...
    <Route path="/question">
      <QFIB />
      <AFIB />
    </Route>
    // `exact` tells the Route is must be... exact
    <Route path="/" exact>
       <Link to="/question">Go to Questions</Link>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: omg i knew it had to do with switches but i kept wrapping the switch around one route rathe than the entire inner part of the Router itself. thanks so much! omg is you again Lynden Noye!!!! hahaha. you are unreal man... any place i could possible PM you about something in specific?

Comment: haha sure! dm me on Twitter https://twitter.com/LyndenNoye